# $wpdb->insert code not working with foreach

Tags: php, sql, foreach, wordpress

**Problem:** There should be a bunch of rows being inserted into the database via $wpdb->insert, but no new rows are created.

Background:

- I've checked the query in PhpMyAdmin and it returns 178 rows.
- This is for a Wordpress plugin with a function that fires on 'init'.
- Have tried various var_dump's and still variables $object_id and $taxo_id appear to be empty.

Please help!

```
<?php
    function cb_t2c_cat_updater () {
    global $wpdb;
    $prefix = $wpdb->prefix;

    //This is a truncated version of the valid SQL query, returns 178 rows
      $cb_t2c_cat_update = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT
      ".$prefix."associations.object_id as 'object_id', ".$prefix."associations.term_taxonomy_id as 'taxo_id', ".$prefix."associations.term_id as 'term_id', ".$prefix."associations.cat_ID as 'cat_ID'
    FROM ...
    WHERE...
    ORDER BY object_id ASC, term_id ASC, cat_ID ASC",ARRAY_A);

    foreach ($cb_t2c_cat_update as $values) {
        $table = $prefix . 'term_relationships';
        $object_id = $values['object_id'];
        $taxo_id = $values['taxo_id'];
        $wpdb->insert(
            $table, 
            array( 
                'object_id' => $object_id, 
                'term_taxonomy_id' => $taxo_id,
                'term_order' => 0
                ), 
            array( 
                '%d', 
                '%d',
                '%d',
                    ) 
            );
        }
    }

add_action('init', 'cb_t2c_cat_updater');

?>
```

Comment: what happens when you var_dump $values in the loop?

Comment: I'm getting a string of the values that I want inserted into the wp table. Actually, that's helpful. I put the var_dump($object_id) and var_dump($taxo_id) in the foreach loop, so at least I know the variables have value. Not sure why the insert isn't working though.

Comment: It's along the lines of `string(1) "9" string(3) "132" string(2) "32" string(3) "103" string(2) "33" string(3) "103" string(2) "34" string(3) "103"` etc.

Comment: Exact same thing if I var_dump($values) like you said. I end up with a ridiculously long bunch of strings.

Comment: and you are sure $table contains the right value? what would $wpdb->insert() return on error? you are sure you are using the method correctly? have you gotten the insert method to work by itself?

Comment: The insert method and the table are both working. I checked the $table variable by setting the array elements 'object_id', 'term_taxonomy_id' and 'term_order' to integers. The database inserted new rows like it should have. I'm wondering if A) My SQL statement is returning data, just the wrong data, so what I expect to happen is not happening, or B) there's a problem with the format of the variables when using $values (i.e., they are strings and need to be converted to integers). Appreciate the help.

Comment: how are you verifying that new rows aren't being created? are you checking phpmyadmin?

Comment: Yes. I'm using phpmyadmin. A new row is are created when the insert statement contains integers, but not when it contains variables. Also, double checked the SQL statement, and it should produce several rows that is the array I'd like to insert through the foreach loop.

Comment: Have a working solution. Made the variables integers through $num_object_id = (int)$object_id, and then passed these into a query like $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO... "). Not sure why $wpdb->insert wasn't working, but $wpdb->query seems to do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I created a new question because I have a more specific error now to point to. The question is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429958/wpdb-insert-produces-duplicate-entry-0-0-for-key-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a working solution.
Made the variables integers through:

```
 $num_object_id = (int)$object_id
```

and then passed these into a query like:

```
$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO... ")
```